# slew of 404 errors on google webmaster tools to plugins/feedback.php file

Tags: facebook, seo, google-crawlers

Got a notification from google webmaster tools that the number of 404 errors have gone up considerably, on inspecting the crawl errors I see a lot of errors to something that shouldn't there:

[webmaster tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSkmq.jpg)

I checked the source code but didnt find a mention of said URL so dont know where google is getting is from. This plugin directory doesn't even exist. Its a WordPress installation so theres a wp-content/plugins folder but no plugins/ folder.

What could be going on.. why is google trynna index a non existent URL and getting a 404.

Site URL is http://ladiesnightandbrunchesdubai.com
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The URL comes from your Facebook comments plugin. I can see the same problem on my site, it started on 24th October.

Comment: If this is caused by Google, it could be becuase of the change in the way they crawl now - they are executing more JavaScript - http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.be/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Answer (score 8):

This URL comes from Facebook Comments plugin. As it is not absolute URL, Google crawler thinks it is pointing to your website.

This probably didn't happen before either because:

1) Google crawler recently started execute more and more javascript - http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.be/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html If this is the case, we could encounter more problems like this with 3rd party scripts on our website.

2) maybe Facebook comments plugin didn't have relative URLs

**Solution:**

Tell Google not to crawl these URLs by adding them to robots.txt

```
Disallow: /plugins/feedback.php
```

Comment: fyi - From past experience I know the 404s will remain in Google Webmaster Tools for months/years until they no longer return a 404. You'll need to add a redirect.

Comment: @sapel - after disallowing  "/plugins/feedback.php" in robots and marking them as fixed in Google Webmaster Tools, none of these URLs appeared in GWT since 30.Oct

Comment: @sapel is kinda right: Just disallowing a URL in robots.txt doenst remove them from reportet 404 pages in "Search Console". You'd have to mark them as fixed there to remove these entries from the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing on my wordpress site. First occurrence was 11/23. There are now around 500 urls and growing.

I've grepped the wordpress codebase and can't find where that path is being constructed and discovered by google.

To fix the 404 report in Webmaster Tools I've added a 301 redirect on '^/plugins/feedback.php' to the homepage. And then marked all as 'Fixed' in Webmaster Tools.